# what's causing my screen to flicker on startup?

Tags: lubuntu, screen, startup, gpu-driver, flicker

When I first installed Lubuntu it worked fine for months. Now when I startup there is this rapid flicker between the display (both the login screen and the general interface after I log in) and black at a rapid clip (like 5-10 alterations per second) for a good while. I haven't exactly timed it but it seems to last progressively longer, maybe around a full minute this time.

Eventually it seems to stop but I'd like to know if there's a way to figure out what is causing it, and maybe a way to fix it. Like if it might be hardware (the monitor or video driver) or something software?

Please tell me if there is something I could input into the terminal to give you information on how to answer this?

---

info update per guiverv and Pilot6:

uname -m output:

> i686

uname -a output:

> Linux KingdomClubs 4.15.0-72-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 26 12:19:40 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' output:

> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce 7350 LE] (rev a1)
>
> Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] G72 [GeForce 7350 LE]
>
> Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
>
> 02:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23418
> Single-Chip MPEG-2 Encoder with Integrated Analog Video/Broadcast
> Audio Decoder

lsb_release -a output:

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 18.04.3
>
> LTS Release:  18.04 Codename: bionic

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. Please also add Lubuntu version.

Comment: Is your architecture amd64 or x86 (i386 in debian/ubuntu terms); *possibly of no value, but I've only see this behavior using 5.3 kernel on 19.10 on unsupported x86; I could not re-produce it on anything else*

Comment: I've added the outputs requested I think? Says 686 so I'm not sure that's issue. It is a 32-bit processor though.

Comment: I would switch from nouveau driver to Nvidia driver

Comment: I see both names listed under kernel modules but I'm not sure how you tell which one is primary and how to alter that state.

Comment: One other thing is that it also does this flicker when I have gone AFK for a while and it goes into automatic sleep mode.